# mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, mount, nfs

I have a external harddrive mounted in /media/hdd and I want to share it with another client, specifically in the folder /mnt/archive. I want to save some files from the client into this harddrive

the steps I have follow are in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04

The IPs are the following:

IP Server: 69.112.130.223
IP Client: 69.112.130.130

I have tried this command:

```
sudo mount -v 69.112.130.223:/media/proton /mnt/archive
```

But I got the following errors:

```
 mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
 mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Oct 29 19:08:13 2018
 mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=69.112.130.223,clientaddr=69.112.130.130'
 mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
 mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 69.112.130.223:/media/proton
```

Client side is UBUNTU 14.04 and the server 18.04

My /etc/exports in the server side looks like this:

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).

/media/proton   69.112.130.130(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

My rpc info on the server side is :

```
rpcinfo -p
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100005    1   udp  57154  mountd
100005    1   tcp  48817  mountd
100005    2   udp  50301  mountd
100005    2   tcp  52587  mountd
100005    3   udp  52789  mountd
100005    3   tcp  57659  mountd
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    3   tcp   2049
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100227    3   udp   2049
100021    1   udp  44354  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  44354  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  44354  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  39665  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  39665  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  39665  nlockmgr
```

and on the client side:

```
rpcinfo -p
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  34223  status
100024    1   tcp  36796  status
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    2   tcp   2049
100227    3   tcp   2049
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    2   udp   2049
100227    3   udp   2049
100021    1   udp   2002  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp   2002  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp   2002  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp   2001  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp   2001  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp   2001  nlockmgr
100005    1   udp   2000  mountd
100005    1   tcp   2000  mountd
100005    2   udp   2000  mountd
100005    2   tcp   2000  mountd
100005    3   udp   2000  mountd
100005    3   tcp   2000  mountd
```

I have added the following line to /etc/hosts.allow on my server side

```
  rpcbind mountd nfsd statd lockd rquotad : 69.112.130.130
```

I am pretty sure that the error has to be something related to the server side and how the permissions are configured but I have looked everywhere and I dont find a solution

I can ping and ssh from client and server side and I can mount the harddrive using ssfhs but I want to use nfs

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when my drive was mounted as /media/xxxx.

I had to mount one of the folder on server and then shared that folder. It worked for me.

Example:

```
$ sudo mount -o bind /mnt/MyRebindPath /media/mysdadrive/Myfolder
```

in /etc/exports

```
 /mnt/MyRebindPath **(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

and on client machine

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs SERVERIP:/mnt/MyRebindPath /mn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too (same as the OP):

`mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied`

And I did the following two steps to get rid of it:

1. Making sure the owner of the exported (and mounted) directories on the server and client side are the same, and that their `gid` and `uid` were the [same on both ends](https://kb.iu.edu/d/adwf).
2. Making sure `/etc/exports` had this format:

   `/home/foo/dir_to_export_to_client client_name_or_ip(options)`

And then running `exportfs -rav` where:

```
-a: Export or unexport all directories.

-r: Reexport all directories

-v: Verbose.
```

NB: If you're running a Linux distribution that uses systemd, it might give you some luck to restart the nfs-server.service every time you make a modification to the server side:

`sudo systemctl restart nfs-server.service`